# cannot load Twig template (Symfony 2.8.8)

Tags: symfony, twig

So I have the folder structure below:

[image]

According to the Symfony manual ([click here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates)), I should be able to load my Twig template but Symfony cannot find it.

[image]

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thank you.

---

**codes I've tried**

```
    return $this->render(
        "AppBundle:DisplayForm.html.twig"
        , array(
            "form" => $form->createView()
    );

    return $this->render(
        "DisplayForm.html.twig"
        , array(
            "form" => $form->createView()
        )
    );
```

**Contents of my app/AppKernel.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),

            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

**contents of app/config/config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are storing the template inside the bundle, you also have to reference the directory within the views - in this case, a 'null' directory.

```
AppBundle::DisplayForm.html.twig
```

Note the `::` for the directory.

If you moved the entire AppBundle/Resources/views/ directory to app/Resources/views/ then you would be able to reference them much as a plain subdirectory:

Referencing templates stored in:

```
app/Resources/views/           | AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/views
 ----------------------------- | ------------------------------- 
index.html.twig                | AcmeDemoBundle::index.html.twig
Default/subdir/index.html.twig | AcmeDemoBundle:Default:subdir/index.html.twig
Default/subdir/index.html.twig | AcmeDemoBundle:Default/subdir:index.html.twig
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have forgotten an `@` symbol:

```
return $this->render(
    "@AppBundle/DisplayForm.html.twig", [ 
        "form" => $form->createView(
    ]
);
```

Comment: I get a different error from Symfony ==>> Malformed namespaced template name "@AppBundle:DisplayForm.html.twig" (expecting "@namespace/template_name").

Comment: i've updated my answer, please try and let me know if it works

Comment: new error: There are no registered paths for namespace "AppBundle". AppBundle came with Symfony when I created a new project using "symfony new my-project lts".

Comment: Is AppBundle registred in app/AppKernel.php ?

Comment: @Alsatian Yes I believe so. I edited my original post to include contents of AppKernel.php and config.yml. The only changes I made to AppKernel.php is to load the Assetic module. Everything else is stock.